# how can i redirect via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to redirect

```
http://abc.com/a to /mypage.php?par1=a and 
http://abc.com/a/b to /mypage.php?par1=a&par2=b
```

how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be enough:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteBase /

  #so i doesn't match a real file/folder
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ mypage.php?par1=$1
  RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ mypage.php?par1=$1&par2=$2
</IfModule>
```